# No inodes left error, df -i command says contrary

Tags: filesystem, files, disk, storage

I copied a lot of files in my mounted Windows drive from Ubuntu and I subsequently ran into `Error opening file '/media/windows/<some-file-path>': No space left on device` error. I checked the output of `df -i` command to see if I had ran out of inodes for the mounted Windows drive:

```
Filesystem        Inodes   IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda5        2363904  504119   1859785   22% /
udev              207621     522    207099    1% /dev
tmpfs             211487     450    211037    1% /run
none              211487       3    211484    1% /run/lock
none              211487       7    211480    1% /run/shm
none              211487      19    211468    1% /run/user
/dev/sda2      458686680 2588876 456097804    1% /media/windows
```

As above output shows, lots of inodes are available for `/media/windows` drive.

I have plenty of disk space left - around 500GB. What's the problem then?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: No, I have not, in fact I have around 500GB of disk space left.

Comment: You said the error was about inodes, but the message you gave says 'no space left on device'.   Was there another error?

Comment: @belacqua: This error happened when I was running a Java program to write files to `/media/windows`. I can still access the files, open them, etc. But I can't create new files.

Comment: @belacqua: Yes, I mean I can't right-click and create a new file either. It's an Operating Systems error.

Comment: It's suspicious that this is a windows directory.  Why did you suspect inodes?

Comment: @belacqua: Oh, because I get java error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /media/windows/<file-path> (No space left on device)` error while running the `Java` program that copies a lot of files from `Ubuntu` to `Windows`.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, problem solved. The Windows drive was corrupted and somehow was preventing Ubuntu to write any data to it. I ran the disk checker program at the start of Windows boot and everything works fine now.